# Where should I start to debug a python program with "Segmentation fault: 11"

Tags: python, debugging, segmentation-fault

I have a python script `test.py`.

Running `python test.py` gives the brief message:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

In general, where should I start to debug such an issue?

Comment: We'll need code to help, but in general you can start by bisecting your code (commenting out roughly half, then seeing if it reproduces, etc.) until you can pinpoint what part of the code is causing the segfault. My bet's on a buggy compiled extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general (and without specifics for your code), the best thing to do is start putting print statements into your test script until you can narrow things down to a single line that is causing the segfault.  Put in a bunch of print statements and move them around as you start narrowing down which print statements run and which ones don't because they are after the segfault.

Answer (score 1):

If your Python script is causing a segmentation fault, that usually means that some Python module that is implemented in C is doing something wrong.  You should be able to tell easily using `gdb`. Try running:

```
gdb `which python`
# This starts an interactive gdb session.  Type:
set args /path/to/python/script.py
r
# The program will now run.  Interact with it until the segfault occurs.  Then type:
bt
```

This will give you the c call stack leading up to the segmentation fault.  (gdb may print a message about missing debug symbols, and give you the command to run to install them.  Debug symbols will give you a more detailed stack trace, including function names and line numbers of files.)  Use this information to more quickly determine what call in Python is causing the segfault.